# What is the performance difference between using a script or iframe tag with src and a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the performance difference between using a script or iframe tag with a `src` attribute.

For example,

```
<script src=“domain.com/script.js”></script>
```

or

```
<iframe src=“domain.com/webpage.html”></iframe>
```

And using an `XMLHttpRequest` to get the contents of a script or iframe then generating a script tag or iframe with the contents of the response from the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is generaly used to make ansychron calls. For example, if you want to make a call to an API to add a new product in your database, you'll make an XMLHttpRequest to http://www.save_a_new_product.com?productId=456, an get the response of it. However, when you do that,the code of http://www.save_a_new_product.com?productId=456 will not be loaded in your page, you just use the script to do something (as save a product in your database)

However, if you want to load a script on your page, for example if you want to be able to use jquery on your page, you have to create a tag of it in the dom. So, you will create a tag script wich src is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js to create an element `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" />` in your page. Is the difference more clear for you ?

Comment: I know the difference between the two. The question is about the performance difference between the methods. And yes I know using an XMLHttpRequest is very unconventional.

Using the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` is the normal way of doing things.

The other way (more hackish, I know) is to get the contents of `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js` using a XMLHttpRequest then creating a HTMLScriptElement and placing the contents of the request inside the script and placing it on the DOM.